# Insert the data into Table C IF The data is not in Table B while Comparing to Table A?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, ssms-2016

I have 2 tables i want to compare the data and insert the difference into 3rd table for example i have

```
table  A

number  Status
1111    C
2222    O
3333    O
4444    C


Table B 

number status
1111    c
2222    O
5555    C
6666    O
```

Now i want to insert data from Table A which is missing from Table B i.e. 3333 and 4444

I have this query

```
Insert into Table C (number,Status)
Select a.number,a.Status from Table A a
left join Table B  b ON b.number = a.number
where B.number is Null
```

But it is inserting Null data into Table C

Comment: This query should work. What do you mean by *inserting null into tableC*?

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server? Please keep only the relevant database tag.

Comment: @GMB i am using sql server i will take care next time. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly fine.

[image]

Please check the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85b701fd415a28bf0fbe6551164db2eb)**.

Answer (score 0):

I tested my logic and posting result

```
insert into tableC (number, status)
select * from tableA
Except
select * from tableb
```